# Count, order desc and select top 4 values for ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, razor, razor-pages

I am trying to create a table that shows the top 4 nationalities in my database for my .NET application. I can do it using SQL following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734769/count-order-desc-and-select-top-5).

This is the result in sql

[image]

However, what I need for my application is

[image]

I have tried using LINQ as well as var in the View but unable to get it. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904458/get-top-5-frequent-values-and-their-total-count-linq-to-sql) and tried following but could not quite understand

Employee Model

```
    public class employees
    {
       public int eeID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }       
       public string Gender { get; set; }
       public string Nationality { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get top 5 frequent values and their total count Linq-to-Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904458/get-top-5-frequent-values-and-their-total-count-linq-to-sql)

Comment: I mentioned it in my question, I saw that but I don't quite understand it. Tried following it. Do I need to create a new class for it?

Comment: You would have to share your asp.net code

Comment: Which part of the code would be relevant? I added the model that i wanted the data from

Comment: You should include your linq code, your dbcontext, your razaor page if you need help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below things

1. Store the Grouped Nationalities sorted as per their counts
2. Get the top results, use `Enumerable.Take`
3. Get the count of the other Nationalities which should not include the top records, For that, you can use `Enumerable.Skip`
4. Concat result from points 2 and 3.
5. Pass the final output to the view.

Sample Code. Please refer to this [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wxoncs) for working code

```
// Your Logic
var topRecordsCount = 4;
var groupedResult = list
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Nationality)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
    
var topRecords = groupedResult
                .Take(topRecordsCount)
                .Select(x => new FinalResult {Nationality = x.Key, Total = x.Count()}).ToList();
var othersCount = groupedResult.Skip(topRecordsCount).Select(x => x.Count()).Sum();
var othersRecord = new FinalResult { Nationality = "Others", Total = othersCount};

topRecords.Add(othersRecord);
foreach(var top in topRecords)
    Console.WriteLine(top.Nationality + " - " + top.Total);
```

---

```
// model to store the final output
public class FinalResult {
     public string Nationality { get; set; }
     public int Total { get; set; }
}
```